# multithreaded SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python-2.7, simplexmlrpcserver

Can someone give a small example of multi threaded SimpleXMLRPCServer. I tried googling around but none of the thins i found were what i needed. Most tell you to use some other library. I have a simple SimpleXMLRPCServer setup, but i don't know where do i add in the multi threading.

dumpServer just has pile of function that i want to call RPC manner. But now i need to add multi threading to it.

```
 dump = dumpServer()
    server_sock = ('127.0.0.1', 7777)
    # Create XML_server
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(server_sock,
                            requestHandler=DumpServerRequestHandler, allow_none=True)
    server.register_introspection_functions()

    # Register all functions of the Mboard instance
    server.register_instance(dump)
```

How can i make it so that it can handle multiple clients simutaneously?